# HomeKit transport layer / Remote Control

Tags: networking, swift, mfi, homekit

Is there any way to change the transport protocol of HomeKit to
a specific one? I would like to control my device remotely.
ie.: tunnel the HTTP traffic over XMPP/websocket. etc?

If no, I know there's a DNS-SD name server to enable wide-area discovery,
but How can I force the HomeKit framwork to search that given domain?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Apple-supported method of changing the transport protocol of HomeKit: it relies directly on HomeKit Accessory Protocol (HAP), which is implemented within iOS itself. Additionally, HomeKit limits its DNS-SD domain to `local.` so your accessory must be present on the current subnet.

The best way to access your HomeKit accessories remotely is to use an Apple TV. Per [Apple's HomeKit support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204893):

> If you have an Apple TV (3rd generation or later) with software version 7.0 or later, you can control your HomeKit-enabled accessories when you're away from home using your iOS device.
>
> Sign into iCloud with the same Apple ID on your iOS device and Apple TV, and you'll be able to use Siri commands to remotely control your accessories.

You may be able to write a simple iOS app that advertises the exact DNS-SD  records of your HomeKit accessory and forwards all traffic above the TCP layer to a server within your home. The home server would then need to connect to the appropriate accessory and forward all traffic above TCP to it. This may not work successfully over a cellular network because I believe DNS-SD will fail, even if its against localhost. I am also not sure that localhost DNS-SD services will be discovered by the system.